# Can one build HTML5 mobile app with Django?

Tags: django, html, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I'd like to know if any developers here have successfully built an HTML5-based mobile web app using Django?  If so, how did you overcome Django's lack of support for some of the newer HTML5 tags and attributes?  If you had it to do over, would you use Django again or some other web framework (e.g. Twitter Bootstrap)?

I'm building a niche dating site that will rely on forms for signup, creating profiles, email,  and so forth. I want it to run, first and foremost, on smartphones and tablets and then computers as a last resort.  I'd like to use HTML5, CSS3, JS, and responsive and progressive design techniques so that users can access all features no matter what type of device they're on.  I'm afraid, though, that Django's lack of support for HTML5 will make building the site very difficult and I'm wondering if I should use a different framework.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Can you give an example of this alleged "lack of support"? As dusual says, Django is a server technology and doesn't care if you're writing HTML5 or not.

Comment: Yes, I believe I can.  When Django renders a text form field based on, say, a model CharField, I don't believe it provides the option to create a type of "tel" or "url" as HTML5 does nor would it allow you to generate HTML5 attributes such as "placeholder" or "required." Instead it would only generate HTML4 tags and attributes. I could be mistaken, but this is my understanding.

Comment: As I have said these attributes can be changed. It would actually be a bad idea for django core to support such form elements as yet. However  if you do want them you can implement yourself

Answer (score 15):

Django is a server side technology . What it provides you is a framework to help you design a scalable backend , It rarely has anything to do with frontend technologies and in case where it provides the frontend functionalities you can always override them . If you wish to have html5 support on some of the django default forms you can always add it/change the way things are rendered . Thats the whole point of MVC.

This is my general view.

However if you have more specific problems with deploying with the framework, you can talk about them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have at least three options:

1. Extend the classes that represent form elements in Django's native template engine so that they contain the HTML5-specific attributes I require.
2. Hand-code templates with the HTML5 tags I want to use instead of relying on Form and ModelForm class instances that I would pass to a template and render via form.as_p, etc.
3. Use an alternate template engine such as django-crispy-forms that directly supports an HTML5 template system like Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Robert, Which one you prefer most in above three, if there is any tutorial link kindly add them also.